# Extracting all subgraphs which do not have duplicated vertex attributes in R

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph

I have a graph object like this:

```
# Create an empty graph
gss <- make_empty_graph(n = 12, directed = FALSE)

# Define vertex attributes
vertex_attr(gss) <- list(
  name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "10", "11", "17", "21", "23"),
  label = c("st_con_rt=main-room", "st_con_rt=sub-room", "st_con_tr=direct", "st_con_tr=terrace", "st_th=tsuma", "st_adsb=add", "st_adsb=sub", "tr_adsb=sub", "st_sub_main_th=hira", "roo_com=1a+7", "roo_com=2a+7", "roo_com=4a"),
  index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 17, 21, 23),
  element = c("st_con_rt", "st_con_rt", "st_con_tr", "st_con_tr", "st_th", "st_adsb", "st_adsb", "tr_adsb", "st_sub_main_th", "roo_com", "roo_com", "roo_com")
)

# Define edges
edges <- c("1", "4", "1", "6", "1", "10", "1", "23", "2", "3", "2", "7", "2", "11", "3", "8", "4", "6", "4", "7", "4", "10", "4", "23", "6", "10", "6", "23", "7", "10", "10", "23", "11", "17", "11", "21")

# Add edges to the graph
gss <- add_edges(gss, edges = edges)
```

I draw two types of this graph; the one with `index` of each node and the other with `element` attribute to easily understand what I need to reach.

```
plot(gss, vertex.label=V(gss)$index)
plot(gss, vertex.label=V(gss)$element)
```

##### Image

[image]
[image]

There are 7 unique values stored in `element`, namely "st_con_rt", "st_con_tr", "st_th", "st_adsb", "tr_adsb", "st_sub_main_th" and "roo_com". This attribute will be used as a conditional graph extraction.

Now, I need to extract all subgraphs which do not contain nodes with the same `element`. I manually checked the graph and a part of the desired result may contain subraphs like this. (Please make sure that `st_con_tr` and `st_con_rt` are different `element`)

[image]

To achive it, I implemented the following process in my script. But unfortunatelly it is not perfectlly implemented and it still contain algorithmic problem.

1. Start loop from a starting node upto the end of node stored in a graph object
2. Check neighboring nodes from a start node and store them in a vector
3. Start iteration to check whether each neighboring node has the same `element`
4. If they have the same element, ignore it
5. If not, save it as a connected node from a starting node
6. Then, goes to that connected node
7. Check neighboring nodes from that connected node (same as #2)
8. Then, continue the same process as in #3-7
9. Once it reached the ending point, it backs to the next neighboring node stored in #3
10. If all branches were checked, go to next start node
11. Accomplish it for all nodes, then remove duplicated subgraphs

In the current script it goes like this. Let me start from node 1.

1. Node 1 connects to node 4, 6, 10 and 23 as neighboring nodes.
2. All neighboring nodes do not have the same `element`, thus it can go 4 directions. Let's start from node 4 in ascending order. Now Node 1 and 4 are connected. This subgraph already contain two `elements`: `roo_com` and `st_con_tr`.
3. Node 4 connects to node 6, 7, 10 and 23 and they do not have the same 'element'. Let's go to node 6. Now node 1, 4 and 6 are connected. Now this subgraph contains `roo_com`, `st_con_tr` and `st_th`.
4. Node 6 connects to node 1, 4, 10 and 23. But in this batch we have already visited node 1 and 4, thus the target nodes are only 10 and 23 of which `element`s are not listed in current subgraph. Let's go to node 10 and connect it to it. Now this subgraph contains `roo_com`, `st_con_tr`, `st_th` and `tr_adsb`.
5. Node 10 connects 1, 4, 6, 7 and 23. As it has already visited node 1, 4, 6, the target nodes are only 7 and 23 of which `element`s are not listed in current subgraph. Let's go to node 7 and connect it to it. Now this subgraph contains `roo_com`, `st_con_tr`, `st_th`, `tr_adsb` and `st_adsb`.
6. Wait, this batch did not visit node 23 although it's `element` is not used. **<= THIS IS AN ALGORITHMIC ISSUE**
7. Now node 7's neighbor is only node 2, but it's `element` is `st_con_rt`. It is already listed in this batch as node 4 has the same `element`. Now the first batch is finished.
8. The next batch starts from node 6, which has already connected to node 1. Then neighbors of node 6 are node 1, 4, 10 and 23. This process will goes on...

I realized that current process cannot obtain what I want. Here is current script, but it also brings strange output, i.e., the branching iteration from subsequent node does does not work as expected, which might be caused by replacing `visited_node` and `stack` during nested loop. I inserted `visited_recur` and `stack_recur` to avoid it but it still remains. Anyway this script contain the fundamental problem mentioned above.

```
## Extract all subgraphs without duplicated "element" values
  # It shall be pre-defined as this function contain itlsef recursively
  
  ## Set recursive function for exploring neighbors
  search_neighbor <- function(graph, current_node, visited_node, stack) {
    
    # Get neighbors of the current node
    neighbors <- neighbors(graph, current_node)
    
    # Explore each neighboring node recursively
    for (neighbor_node in neighbors[!visited_node[neighbors]]) {
      if (vertex_attr(graph)$element[current_node] != vertex_attr(graph)$element[neighbor_node]) {
      
      print(paste0("# Recursive search: node ", current_node, " connected to node ", neighbor_node))

      # Update visited node not to revisit
        visited_node[neighbor_node] <- TRUE
      
      # Add the node to the connected subgraph
        stack <- c(stack, neighbor_node)
        
      # Recursive process to go to next neighbor node
        stack <- search_neighbor(gss, neighbor_node, visited_node, stack)
      
      }
    }
  }
  
## Initialize subgraph to store connected nodes and edges
  list_subgraph <- list()
  
## Initialize i
  i <- 1
  
  ## Iteration for all nodes as starting point
  for (start_node in V(gss)) {
    
    # Initialize visited nodes as all FALSE from node list in the graph
    visited_node <- logical(length(V(gss)))
    visited_node[start_node] <- TRUE
    
    # Stack start node as starting point
    stack <- start_node
    
    # Search neighboring nodes from start node
    neighbors <- neighbors(gss, start_node)
    
    # Start node as current node as starting point
    current_node <- start_node
    
    print(paste0("// Start from node ", current_node))
    
      # Iteration for neighboring nodes
      for (neighbor_node in neighbors[!visited_node[neighbors]]) {
        
        # Initialize an empty graph for the connected subgraph
        connected_subgraph <- make_empty_graph(n = 0, directed = FALSE)

        # Check if neighboring node contains a different element
        if (vertex_attr(gss)$element[current_node] != vertex_attr(gss)$element[neighbor_node]) {
          
          print(paste0("Node ", current_node, " connected to node ", neighbor_node))
          
          # Add neighboring node to subgraph
          stack <- c(stack, neighbor_node) ; stack_recur <- stack
          # Update visited node not to revisit
          visited_node[neighbor_node] <- TRUE ; visited_recur <- visited_node

          # Recursive exploration of neighbors from current neighbor node till the end
          search_neighbor(gss, neighbor_node, visited_recur, stack_recur)
          
          # Store connected subgraph
          connected_subgraph <- subgraph(gss, stack)
          
        }
        
        print(paste0("\\ Finished #", i, " search neighbors:", paste(stack, collapse = ", ")))
        
        # Store extracted subgraph from search result
        list_subgraph[[i]] <- connected_subgraph
        
        # Update i
        i <- i + 1
        
      }
    }

  # Remove duplicated subtracted graphs
  unique_subgraphs <- unique(list_subgraph)
```

I am not sure whether this complicated issue can be asked in this forum as it does not specify the scripting problem. Hope if someone can provide any insights to improve it. I hope if there are any functions which can solve this issue without implementing complicated searching approach.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your illustration: vertex 1 and 2 shouldn't be in the same subgraph since they have the same `element` attribute

Comment: Yes, vertes 1 and 2 have the same element `roo_com`. I checked the figure and updated it refering to your output as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
# split vertices by `element` attribute, and filter connected subgraphs
lst <- unique(
  Filter(
    \(x) length(x) > 1,
    unlist(
      apply(
        expand.grid(split(V(gss), V(gss)$element)),
        1,
        \(x) {
          lapply(
            decompose(induced_subgraph(gss, x)),
            \(g) V(g)$name
          )
        }
      ),
      recursive = FALSE
    )
  )
)

# merging subgraphs, to avoid duplicated small subgraphs, where `lst` saves the potential subgraph vertex names. 
repeat {
  lgl <- rep(TRUE, length(lst))
  for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
    p <- lst[[k]]
    if (any(sapply(lst[-k], \(x) all(p %in% x)))) {
      lgl[k] <- FALSE
    }
  }
  if (all(lgl)) break
  lst <- lst[lgl]
}

# induce subgraph by vertex names
out <- lapply(lst, induced_subgraph, graph = gss)
```

where `out` is a list of all subgraphs in which all vertices have distinct `element` attribute

```
> out
[[1]]
IGRAPH ec008ca UN-- 7 6 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec008ca (vertex names):
[1] 2 --3  2 --7  2 --11 6 --10 7 --10 11--17

[[2]]
IGRAPH ec009a9 UN-- 7 6 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec009a9 (vertex names):
[1] 2 --3  2 --7  2 --11 6 --10 7 --10 11--21

[[3]]
IGRAPH ec00a4b UN-- 7 7 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00a4b (vertex names):
[1] 2 --3  2 --7  2 --11 6 --10 6 --23 7 --10 10--23

[[4]]
IGRAPH ec00ae0 UN-- 5 4 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00ae0 (vertex names):
[1] 2 --3  3 --8  2 --11 11--17

[[5]]
IGRAPH ec00b75 UN-- 5 4 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00b75 (vertex names):
[1] 2 --3  3 --8  2 --11 11--21

[[6]]
IGRAPH ec00c12 UN-- 6 12 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00c12 (vertex names):
 [1] 1 --4  1 --6  4 --6  4 --7  1 --10 4 --10 6 --10 7 --10 1 --23 4 --23
[11] 6 --23 10--23

[[7]]
IGRAPH ec00c8f UN-- 7 8 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00c8f (vertex names):
[1] 2 --7  2 --11 4 --6  4 --7  4 --10 6 --10 7 --10 11--17

[[8]]
IGRAPH ec00d00 UN-- 7 8 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00d00 (vertex names):
[1] 2 --7  2 --11 4 --6  4 --7  4 --10 6 --10 7 --10 11--21

[[9]]
IGRAPH ec00d6a UN-- 7 10 --
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), index (v/n), element (v/c)
+ edges from ec00d6a (vertex names):
 [1] 2 --7  2 --11 4 --6  4 --7  4 --10 4 --23 6 --10 6 --23 7 --10 10--23
```

---

## Visualization

```
nr <- 3
par(mfrow = c(nr, ceiling(length(lst) / nr)))
lo <- layout.auto(gss)
for (k in seq_along(lst)) {
  plot(
    gss,
    layout = lo,
    vertex.label = V(gss)$name,
    vertex.color = ifelse(V(gss)$name %in% lst[[k]], "green", "yellow"),
    vertex.size = 20,
    main = paste0("subgraph ", k)
  )
}
```

where the vertices highlighted in green indicate the desired subgraphs.
[image]

Comment: It is really powerful script with efficiency. Thanks a lot! I also updated an image based on the result.
I was trying another approach, generating all combinations of nodes with `all_simple_paths` function and remove unnecessary graphs. I could remove most of unnecessary subgraphs such as `element` duplication, but I was struggling with removing non-maximal subgraphs from remaining subgraphs.

Comment: @HSJ I am curious how you made those fancy boundaries. Could you share your code? :P

Comment: I hope if I could provide the code, but it is manually drawn by MS PPT ;P
I wish if I could automate it!!

Comment: @HSJ Aha, now I understand. Anyway, your plot looks cool! I tried another way of presenting the subgraphs, please check the update.

Comment: Thank you for your new code, it look really cool and super useful. I'd give 10 times `useful` to your answer!